# Alignment of columns in email body using powershell

Tags: html, powershell

I have below code to get the data in table format in email body.

Right now I am getting all the columns as right aligned.

But I need first three columns to be left aligned.

Please let me know how can I achieve this. I am running this code in PowerShell.exe

Any suggestions would help me

Code used is as below

Code.ps1

```
<# Param(
  [Parameter(
  Mandatory = $true,
  ParameterSetName = '',
  ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
  [string]$Query
  )
 #> 
$Query = "declare @todate datetime=(select dateadd(day, datediff(day,0, '2020-03-02'),'7:00'));
    select ytd.site_id SiteId,ytd.site_name SiteName,ytd.Region,
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY, round(sum(mtd.budgettarget),2)),1), '.00','') 'MTD_Budget Target',
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY, round(sum(MTD.IncentiveTarget),2)),1), '.00','')'MTD_Incentive Target' ,
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY,  round(sum(mtd.NetAmount),2)),1), '.00','') 'MTD_Net Amount',
     round(AVG(mtd.ActualVsBudget),4) 'MTD_Actual Vs Budget',
    round(AVG(mtd.ActualVsIncentive),4) 'MTD_Actual Vs Incentive' ,
     REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY, round(sum(ytd.budgettarget),2)),1), '.00','') 'YTD_Budget Target',
     REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY, round(sum(ytd.IncentiveTarget),2)),1), '.00','') 'YTD_Incentive Target'
     , REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY,round(sum(ytd.NetAmount),2)),1), '.00','') 'YTD_Net Amount',
      round(AVG(ytd.ActualVsBudget),4) 'YTD_Actual Vs Budget',
     round(AVG(ytd.ActualVsIncentive),4) 'YTD_Actual Vs Incentive'
    from
      (
      select b1.site_id,b1.Site_Name,b1.region,Convert(date, b1.trxdate, 102) ReportDate,--b1.Region,
     b1.amount1 BudgetTarget,b1.amount1*1.02 IncentiveTarget,               
             sum(net_Amount) NetAmount,             
              ((sum(net_Amount)- b1.amount1)/(b1.amount1)) ActualVsBudget   ,
               ((sum(net_Amount)- (b1.amount1*1.02))/(b1.amount1*1.02)) ActualVsIncentive       
              from      
              (
                select fbd1.date date2,fbd1.amount amount1,fcr.region, tl1.trxid,v1.trxdate,v1.amount,s1.site_id,s1.site_name,          
                case when v1.product_name='Refund Card' and v1.net_amount =0 and v1.amount <> 0 and isnull(v1.tax,0)=0  
                     then v1.amount
                     else (v1.net_amount*(1-isnull((td1.discountpercentage/100),0))) 
                     end net_amount
                  from TransactionView v1 
                  left join trx_lines tl1 on v1.trxid = tl1.trxid and v1.lineid=tl1.LineId
                  left outer join TrxDiscounts td1 on td1.trxid = tl1.trxid and td1.lineid = tl1.lineid 
                  left join site s1 on tl1.site_id = s1.site_id 
                  left outer join fc_budget_data fbd1 on Convert(date, v1.trxdate, 102) =Convert(date, fbd1.date, 102) and fbd1.sitecode=s1.site_id 
                   left join fc_region fcr on fcr.sitecode = s1.site_id
                  where trxdate >= dateadd(month,datediff(month,'1900-04-01', @ToDate)/12*12,'1900-04-01') 
                  and v1.trxdate <= @ToDate 
                  and s1.active_flag ='Y'
                  --and v1.trxid = tl1.trxid 
                  --and s1.site_id = 1019
              ) b1              
              group by b1.site_id,b1.site_name,b1.region,b1.amount1,Convert(date, b1.trxdate, 102)  
              )ytd
               left outer join (
               select b.site_id,b.Site_Name,b.region,Convert(date, trxdate, 102) ReportDate,
              b.amount1 BudgetTarget,b.amount1*1.02 IncentiveTarget,                
             sum(net_Amount) NetAmount,             
              ((sum(net_Amount)-b.amount1)/b.amount1) ActualVsBudget,
              ((sum(net_Amount)-(b.amount1*1.02))/(b.amount1*1.02)) ActualVsIncentive       
              from          
              (     
                select fbd.date date2,fbd.amount amount1,fcr.region, v.trxid,trxdate,v.amount,s.site_id,s.site_name,            
                case when product_name='Refund Card' and net_amount =0 and v.amount <> 0 and isnull(tax,0)=0    
                     then v.amount
                     else (v.net_amount*(1-isnull((td.discountpercentage/100),0))) 
                     end net_amount
                  from TransactionView v 
                  left join trx_lines tl on v.trxid = tl.trxid and v.lineid=tl.LineId
                  left outer join TrxDiscounts td on td.trxid = tl.trxid and td.lineid = tl.lineid  
                  left join site s on tl.site_id = s.site_id    
                  left outer join fc_budget_data fbd on Convert(date, trxdate, 102) =Convert(date, fbd.date, 102) and fbd.sitecode=s.site_id    
                   left join fc_region fcr on fcr.sitecode = s.site_id
                  where trxdate >= dateadd(day,1,EOMONTH(@ToDate,-1)) and trxdate <= @ToDate
                   and s.active_flag ='Y'   
                  --and v.trxid = tl.trxid 
                  --and s.site_id = 1015    
              ) b               
             group by b.site_id,b.site_name,b.region,b.amount1  ,Convert(date, trxdate, 102) 
             ) MTD on mtd.site_id=ytd.site_id and mtd.reportdate=ytd.reportdate
        --   left join (select distinct sitecode,site, region from fc_budget_data)fcr on mtd.site_id= fcr.SiteCode 
    --       and ytd.site_id = 1011
        group by  ytd.site_id,ytd.site_name,ytd.Region"
$MySQLAdminUserName = 'parafaitreadonly'
[Int32]$QueryTimeout=90
$MySQLAdminPassword = 'Semnox@123'
$MySQLDatabase = 'Parafait'
$MySQLHost = 'SEMNOXHOSERVER'
$ConnectionString = "server=" + $MySQLHost + ";uid=" + $MySQLAdminUserName + ";pwd=" + $MySQLAdminPassword + ";database="+$MySQLDatabase
$Time = '2020-03-02 07:00'
Try {
  [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
  $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
  $Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
  $Connection.Open()
  $Command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query, $Connection)
  $Command.CommandTimeout=$QueryTimeout
  $DataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($Command)
  $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
  $RecordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")
  echo "spooling to csv"
  # pause
  $Dataset.Tables[0] | Export-Csv -path "C:\Temp\Reportscedule\Sales Vs Budget ReportTest.csv" -NoTypeInformation
  }
Catch {
  Write-Host "ERROR : Unable to run query : $query `n$Error[0]"
 }
Finally {
  $Connection.Close()
  }
echo "csv created"
# pause

$user = "itsupport.citymax@landmarkgroup.in"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "welcome@20" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $user, $pass
##$body = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\TestJava.csv" | Out-String
$Header = @"
<style> TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
 TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}</style>
"@
##$body = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\TestJava.csv" | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header -Fragment  | Out-String
#$summ = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\Reportscedule\Sales Vs Budget ReportTest.csv'
#$body = "Please find attached following reports in the mail"+"<br>`r`n"+"<br>`r`n"+
"Sales Vs Budget Report: "+"$Time"+"<br>`r`n"+"<br>`r`n" 
$body = "Please find attached following reports in the mail"+"<br>`r`n"+"<br>`r`n"+
"Sales Vs Budget Report: "+"$Time"+"<br>`r`n"+"<br>`r`n

"
$body+= Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\Reportscedule\Sales Vs Budget ReportTest.csv"| ConvertTo-Html -Head $format | Out-String
$body= $body -replace "<table", "<table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;'"
$body = $body -replace "<th", "<th border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; border-collapse: collapse; padding:5px;'"
$body = $body -replace "<td", "<td border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding:5px;text-align: right'" 
$body=$body -replace"<td align=Left><b>SiteName</b></td>'"
$mailParam = @{
        To = @('prajna.b@semnox.com')
        From = "Funcity HQ<itsupport.citymax@landmarkgroup.in>"
        Subject = "Parafait Schedule Report -Sales Vs Budget ReportTest"
        Body = $body
        SmtpServer = "smtp.office365.com"
        Port = 587
        Credential = $cred
        Attachment = "C:\Temp\Reportscedule\Sales Vs Budget ReportTest.csv"
    }
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'TLS,TLS11,TLS12'
IF ((Get-Item 'C:\Temp\Reportscedule\Sales Vs Budget ReportTest.csv').length -gt 0kb)
{
echo "Sending email"
Send-MailMessage @mailParam -BodyAsHtml -Usessl
# pause
}
echo "Check your mail box - I am done "
# Pause
```

Comment: As aside: you are using `ConvertTo-Html -Head $format`, where this variable `$format` is never defined

Answer (score 0):

I had added it before but it didnot work

Below is the code that was used

```
<# Param(
  [Parameter(
  Mandatory = $true,
  ParameterSetName = '',
  ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
  [string]$Query
  )
 #> 
$Query = "declare @todate datetime=(select dateadd(day, datediff(day,0, '2020-03-02'),'7:00'));
    select ytd.site_id SiteId,ytd.site_name SiteName,ytd.Region,
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY, round(sum(mtd.budgettarget),2)),1), '.00','') 'MTD_Budget Target',
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY, round(sum(MTD.IncentiveTarget),2)),1), '.00','')'MTD_Incentive Target' ,
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY,  round(sum(mtd.NetAmount),2)),1), '.00','') 'MTD_Net Amount',
     round(AVG(mtd.ActualVsBudget),4) 'MTD_Actual Vs Budget',
    round(AVG(mtd.ActualVsIncentive),4) 'MTD_Actual Vs Incentive' ,
     REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY, round(sum(ytd.budgettarget),2)),1), '.00','') 'YTD_Budget Target',
     REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY, round(sum(ytd.IncentiveTarget),2)),1), '.00','') 'YTD_Incentive Target'
     , REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY,round(sum(ytd.NetAmount),2)),1), '.00','') 'YTD_Net Amount',
      round(AVG(ytd.ActualVsBudget),4) 'YTD_Actual Vs Budget',
     round(AVG(ytd.ActualVsIncentive),4) 'YTD_Actual Vs Incentive'
    from
      (
      select b1.site_id,b1.Site_Name,b1.region,Convert(date, b1.trxdate, 102) ReportDate,--b1.Region,
     b1.amount1 BudgetTarget,b1.amount1*1.02 IncentiveTarget,               
             sum(net_Amount) NetAmount,             
              ((sum(net_Amount)- b1.amount1)/(b1.amount1)) ActualVsBudget   ,
               ((sum(net_Amount)- (b1.amount1*1.02))/(b1.amount1*1.02)) ActualVsIncentive       
              from      
              (
                select fbd1.date date2,fbd1.amount amount1,fcr.region, tl1.trxid,v1.trxdate,v1.amount,s1.site_id,s1.site_name,          
                case when v1.product_name='Refund Card' and v1.net_amount =0 and v1.amount <> 0 and isnull(v1.tax,0)=0  
                     then v1.amount
                     else (v1.net_amount*(1-isnull((td1.discountpercentage/100),0))) 
                     end net_amount
                  from TransactionView v1 
                  left join trx_lines tl1 on v1.trxid = tl1.trxid and v1.lineid=tl1.LineId
                  left outer join TrxDiscounts td1 on td1.trxid = tl1.trxid and td1.lineid = tl1.lineid 
                  left join site s1 on tl1.site_id = s1.site_id 
                  left outer join fc_budget_data fbd1 on Convert(date, v1.trxdate, 102) =Convert(date, fbd1.date, 102) and fbd1.sitecode=s1.site_id 
                   left join fc_region fcr on fcr.sitecode = s1.site_id
                  where trxdate >= dateadd(month,datediff(month,'1900-04-01', @ToDate)/12*12,'1900-04-01') 
                  and v1.trxdate <= @ToDate 
                  and s1.active_flag ='Y'
                  --and v1.trxid = tl1.trxid 
                  --and s1.site_id = 1019
              ) b1              
              group by b1.site_id,b1.site_name,b1.region,b1.amount1,Convert(date, b1.trxdate, 102)  
              )ytd
               left outer join (
               select b.site_id,b.Site_Name,b.region,Convert(date, trxdate, 102) ReportDate,
              b.amount1 BudgetTarget,b.amount1*1.02 IncentiveTarget,                
             sum(net_Amount) NetAmount,             
              ((sum(net_Amount)-b.amount1)/b.amount1) ActualVsBudget,
              ((sum(net_Amount)-(b.amount1*1.02))/(b.amount1*1.02)) ActualVsIncentive       
              from          
              (     
                select fbd.date date2,fbd.amount amount1,fcr.region, v.trxid,trxdate,v.amount,s.site_id,s.site_name,            
                case when product_name='Refund Card' and net_amount =0 and v.amount <> 0 and isnull(tax,0)=0    
                     then v.amount
                     else (v.net_amount*(1-isnull((td.discountpercentage/100),0))) 
                     end net_amount
                  from TransactionView v 
                  left join trx_lines tl on v.trxid = tl.trxid and v.lineid=tl.LineId
                  left outer join TrxDiscounts td on td.trxid = tl.trxid and td.lineid = tl.lineid  
                  left join site s on tl.site_id = s.site_id    
                  left outer join fc_budget_data fbd on Convert(date, trxdate, 102) =Convert(date, fbd.date, 102) and fbd.sitecode=s.site_id    
                   left join fc_region fcr on fcr.sitecode = s.site_id
                  where trxdate >= dateadd(day,1,EOMONTH(@ToDate,-1)) and trxdate <= @ToDate
                   and s.active_flag ='Y'   
                  --and v.trxid = tl.trxid 
                  --and s.site_id = 1015    
              ) b               
             group by b.site_id,b.site_name,b.region,b.amount1  ,Convert(date, trxdate, 102) 
             ) MTD on mtd.site_id=ytd.site_id and mtd.reportdate=ytd.reportdate
        --   left join (select distinct sitecode,site, region from fc_budget_data)fcr on mtd.site_id= fcr.SiteCode 
    --       and ytd.site_id = 1011
        group by  ytd.site_id,ytd.site_name,ytd.Region"
$MySQLAdminUserName = 'parafaitreadonly'
[Int32]$QueryTimeout=90
$MySQLAdminPassword = 'Semnox@123'
$MySQLDatabase = 'Parafait'
$MySQLHost = 'SEMNOXHOSERVER'
$ConnectionString = "server=" + $MySQLHost + ";uid=" + $MySQLAdminUserName + ";pwd=" + $MySQLAdminPassword + ";database="+$MySQLDatabase
$Time = '2020-03-02 07:00'
Try {
  [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
  $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
  $Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
  $Connection.Open()
  $Command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query, $Connection)
  $Command.CommandTimeout=$QueryTimeout
  $DataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($Command)
  $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
  $RecordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")
  echo "spooling to csv"
  # pause
  $Dataset.Tables[0] | Export-Csv -path "C:\Temp\Reportscedule\Sales Vs Budget ReportTest.csv" -NoTypeInformation
  }
Catch {
  Write-Host "ERROR : Unable to run query : $query `n$Error[0]"
 }
Finally {
  $Connection.Close()
  }
echo "csv created"
# pause

$user = "itsupport.citymax@landmarkgroup.in"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "welcome@20" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $user, $pass
##$body = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\TestJava.csv" | Out-String
$Header = @"
<style> TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
 TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}</style>
"@
$format = @"
<style>
  body {
    background-color: White;
  }
  table {
   border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  th {
   border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; border-collapse: collapse; padding:5px;
  }
  td {
   border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding:5px;

  }
  td:nth-child(1) {
    text-align: left;
  }
  td:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: Left;
  }
  td:nth-child(3) {
    text-align: Left;
  }
  td:nth-child(4) {
    text-align: Right;
  }
</style>
"@
##$body = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\TestJava.csv" | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header -Fragment  | Out-String
#$summ = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\Reportscedule\Sales Vs Budget ReportTest.csv'
#$body = "Please find attached following reports in the mail"+"<br>`r`n"+"<br>`r`n"+
"Sales Vs Budget Report: "+"$Time"+"<br>`r`n"+"<br>`r`n" 
$body = "Please find attached following reports in the mail"+"<br>`r`n"+"<br>`r`n"+
"Sales Vs Budget Report: "+"$Time"+"<br>`r`n"+"<br>`r`n

"
$body+= Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\Reportscedule\Sales Vs Budget ReportTest.csv"| ConvertTo-Html -Head $format | Out-String
$body= $body -replace "<table", "<table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;'"
$body = $body -replace "<th", "<th border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; border-collapse: collapse; padding:5px;'"
$body = $body -replace "<td", "<td border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding:5px;text-align: right'" 
$body=$body -replace"<td align=Left><b>SiteName</b></td>'"
$mailParam = @{
        To = @('prajna.b@semnox.com')
        From = "Funcity HQ<itsupport.citymax@landmarkgroup.in>"
        Subject = "Parafait Schedule Report -Sales Vs Budget ReportTest"
        Body = $body
        SmtpServer = "smtp.office365.com"
        Port = 587
        Credential = $cred
        Attachment = "C:\Temp\Reportscedule\Sales Vs Budget ReportTest.csv"
    }
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'TLS,TLS11,TLS12'
IF ((Get-Item 'C:\Temp\Reportscedule\Sales Vs Budget ReportTest.csv').length -gt 0kb)
{
echo "Sending email"
Send-MailMessage @mailParam -BodyAsHtml -Usessl
# pause
}
echo "Check your mail box - I am done "
# Pause
```